# Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

Tags: python, typeerror

My code:

```
total=tef+tpf-price
```

I've got this error:

```
  total=tef+tpf-price
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: The question looks totally different from the original question.  Please change it back, and start a new question.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of this

```
total=tef+tpf-price
```

Try this, I hope this will help you

```
total=float(tef)+float(float)tpf-float(price)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might take user's `price` input, like:

```
price = raw_input('--> ')    // Python 2.x
```

or

```
price = input('--> ')        // Python 3.x
```

So you might want to do some validation before using it.

You could cast `price` from string to float by `float(price)`.

Comment: Edited the question, how do I fix this?

Comment: You need to cast everything to float

Comment: Can you do it for me please?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to fix it is:

```
tef=float(price)*5/100.0
```

Comment: Edited the question, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that error could occur is if `price` is a string.  Make price a float or an integer (depending on what you want) to fix the problem.

Either this:

```
tef=float(price)*5/100.0
```

or this:

```
tef=int(price)*5/100.0
```

Notice that, in Python, to preform an operation between two objects, those object must be of the same type (and support the operation of course).

Comment: Edited the question, how do I fix this?

Comment: @user2899653 - You have to make sure all of those variables are of the same type.  Most likely, this will mean making them all floats.

Comment: Can you do it for me please?

Comment: @user2899653 - Well, I don't know your code, so the best I can do is:  `total=float(tef)+float(tpf)-float(price)`.