# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float' in a 'tip calculator

Tags: python

```
print("Welcome to the tip calculator!")
bill = float(input("What was the total bill? £"))
tip = int(input("how much tip would you like to leave? 10, 12, or 15?"))

billWithTip = str(tip / 100 * bill + bill)
print("the final price is £" + billWithTip)
totalBill = billWithTip
people = float(input("how many people should split the bill?"))
totalBill2 = totalBill / people 
print(totalBill2)
```

I am getting the error  at the end

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: when you do `billWithTip = str(tip / 100 * bill + bill)`  you have a string. Later you do `totalBill = billWithTip`  and finally you do `totalBill / people` which is a division between a string and an int

Comment: You are trying to divide text over number. You can't do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480060/python-typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-float)

Comment: Note - you do not need to convert a number to a string before using `print()`. You can just use `print('message', my_number)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation in the comments

```
print("Welcome to the tip calculator!")
bill = float(input("What was the total bill? £"))
tip = int(input("how much tip would you like to leave? 10, 12, or 15?"))

# instead of converting to a string here
# billWithTip = str(tip / 100 * bill + bill)

# keep it as a number
billWithTip = tip / 100 * bill + bill

# and do the convertion here, inside the print
print("the final price is £" + str(billWithTip))

# or even better, use f-strings
# print(f"the final price is £{billWithTip}")


totalBill = billWithTip

# unless this is Jack the Ripper tip calculator ™
# you probably want an integer number of people here.
people = float(input("how many people should split the bill?"))

# bad variable name, totalBillPerPerson would be better 
# (try using descriptive variable names)
totalBill2 = totalBill / people 
print(totalBill2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Welcome to the tip calculator!")
bill=float(input("what was the total bill? \n"))
tip=int(input("how much tip would you like to leave?\n"))
billwithtip=float(tip/100*bill+bill) #instead of using string type you can use float or int
print("the final price is:",billwithtip)
totalbill=billwithtip
people=float(input("how many people should split the bill?\n"))
totalbill2=totalbill/people
print(totalbill2)
print("Welcome to the tip calculator!")
```

Comment: the value is already a float, no need to convert it to a float. Converting it to an int would make the restaurant owner not very happy since 12.99 will become 12.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform arithmetic on strings unless you convert them to appropriate data types (if indeed they can be converted). In your case you explicitly construct billWithTip as a string type. totalBill will also be a string because it's just a reference to billWithTip.

Your code requires input of two different types (int and float). One of the int values needs to be one of 3 possible values.

Nowhere in your code do you attempt to validate any of the input. You should **always** validate user input.

Here's a more elaborate but consequently more robust implementation:

```
def getvalue(prompt, ntype):
    while True:
        try:
            return ntype(input(prompt))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

print("Welcome to the tip calculator")

bill = getvalue("What was the total bill? ", float)

while not (tip := getvalue("How much tip would you like to leave? 10, 12, or 15? ", int)) in {10, 12, 15}:
    print("Invalid tip percentage")

while (people := getvalue("How many people should split the bill? ", int)) < 1:
    print("Must be at least one person")

billWithTip = bill * (1 + tip / 100)

print(f"The final price is £{billWithTip:.2f}")
print(f"Cost per person is £{billWithTip/people:.2f}")
```