# in python - while loop isnt working, its leading to print else statemnt continously after entering the invalid option

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

[image: the output its giving]i am learning python and trying to use while loop, but getting else print statement continoulsy if entering the invalid tip_val

```
def tip():
        print("Welcome to the tip calculator")
        bill = float(input("what is the total bill :"))
        ppl = int(input("how mny people spilt the bill :"))
        tip_val = int(input("what percentage of tip you would like to give i.e 10 or 12 or 15 :"))

        while True:
            if tip_val in (10, 12, 15):
                break
            else:
                print("invalid choice,please enter the valid discount from 10/12/15 ")
    
        disc_amount = (tip_val * bill) / 100
        total_amount = disc_amount + bill
        amount_per_prsn = total_amount / ppl
        print(f"discount amount is :{disc_amount}")
        print(f"total amount is :{total_amount}")
        print(f"each person got :{amount_per_prsn}")

tip()
```

Comment: If the value of *tip_val* is not in the tuple, you will print "invalid choice..." and because *tip_val* doesn't change then you'll stay in the loop *ad infinitum*

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77926789/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-str-and-float-in-a-tip-calcul/77946689#77946689)

Answer (score 1):

You need to redefine the value *inside* the loop, otherwise it's just checking the same value over and over again:

```py
def tip():
    print("Welcome to the tip calculator")
    bill = float(input("what is the total bill :"))
    ppl = int(input("how mny people spilt the bill :"))

    # move the tip calculation down here
    while True:
        tip_val = int(input("what percentage of tip you would like to give i.e 10 or 12 or 15 :"))

        if tip_val in (10, 12, 15):
            break
    
        # You don't need an "else" because the "if"
        # will terminate further loop execution
        print("invalid choice,please enter the valid discount from 10/12/15 ")

    disc_amount = (tip_val * bill) / 100
    total_amount = disc_amount + bill
    amount_per_prsn = total_amount / ppl
    print(f"discount amount is :{disc_amount}")
    print(f"total amount is :{total_amount}")
    print(f"each person got :{amount_per_prsn}")
```

Comment: still getting the same

Comment: @PrashantKumar - Perhaps you are still running the other code? This worked for me.

Comment: @PrashantKumar there is no way you are getting the same unless you are inputting a `tip_val` that isn't either 10, 12, or 15

Comment: @C.Nivs thanks, it worked.i was defining the tip_val outside the loop